# Uncaught TypeError for download product magento 2.2.7 admin

Tags: product, admin, magento2.2, downloadable, magento2.2.7

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to
>   Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name::truncateString() must
>   be of the type string, null given, called in
>   /vendor/magento/module-downloadable/view/adminhtml/templates/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
>   on line 25 and defined in
>   /vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Items/Column/Name.php:36 in magento 2.2.7

I have disabled all third party extension.

Answer (score 0):

**Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed**

Please follow below steps

**Step 1** remove the var folder from magento root.

**Step 2** remove the generated folder from magento root.

**Step 3** clear cache and check it again.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari please check full report of error any file from generated.

Comment: This is Magento open issue : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16958